# How to specify breakpoint condition to "less than" on hit count?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I specify conditions for a breakpoint, I can relate to the hit count in three ways.

- larger or equal to
- equal to
- multiple of

Right now, I'd really need to set it to **less than** but there's no such option. Googlearching gave me that it's so uncommonly used feature that I'm not supposed to need it.

I haven't figured out a work-around other than setting **multiple of** to something really large in combination with a bunch of **equal to** for 1, 2, 3 etc. Hardly an efficient solution.

Any other hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to be able to do this as well, for some time now, but it doesn't seem to be a built-in feature. The best I have been able to do is set `hitcount =1` and just accept that the feature to pick larger values does not exist.

However, there are some workarounds:

Potentially, you can call a function that performs a logic branch on some artificial criteria close to your needs and put a break point in only one fork, but that's potentially time consuming.

Alternatively, you could go into the breakpoints window and disable the breakpoints you don't want to hit any more, and then re-enable them on the next run.

Depending on circumstances these may or may not be any better than what your are currently doing.